# iOS keep search results when returning to search page

Tags: ios, uisearchcontroller

I have one view controller with search controller to search something, so basically if I clicked on one result(function 0didSelectTableviewcell called), the application will jump to a new view controller to display some information. If I want to click return to go back to the search view controller, the search result is gone. So any ideas about keeping the result? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Segues or pushViewController?

The easiest way in my mind would be:

I would create a property in the first controller that is a string variable(or whatever is easiest for you to use as a search item). Let's call it "mySearchTerm"

Then, just like when you pass the information to ViewController2 to get the details of the selected table view cell, you can pass that same information back from ViewController2 to ViewController1 when you return. I assume the selected indexPath contained reference to the search string used in ViewController1, so this is what we will be passing back when we return to it.

So, when you leave ViewController2 to go back to the original one, you would set the "mySearchTerm" property of ViewController1(viewController1.mySearchTerm) to whatever the original search term was.

Then, when ViewController1 loads, have a function that checks if that string variable is nil, if it is not, you can access the value that was passed from ViewController2 and just implement a new search with it on load.

Does this help with what you are trying to do?